# How to update a tile from ShareStatusTask

Tags: windows-phone-7

I would like to be able to update a secondary tile that is pinned to the start screen when the user finishes using the ShareStatusTask option available in my application. The problem is that the user may also navigate to my ShareStatusPage which contains the ShareStatusTask from the secondary tile as well, but I allow the user to create the secondary tile in my MainPage. Therefore, I do not know how to update the tile instance in my MainPage from the ShareStatusPage when there is no backstack navigation? How would I be able to declare a global variable that would accomplish this immediately while keeping the default backstack navigation (not going to MainPage when the ShareStatusPage is accessed from the secondary tile on the start screen)? My ultimate goal is to simply update the message of the secondary tile with the most recent status update text (which is input by the user in my ShareStatusPage before the ShareStatusTask is called).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep a status property in a viewModel and refer it on your both pages. Thus whenever that property value is changed, call a updateTile function which would change your secondary tile. You may learn how to implement the [MVVM architecture](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/gg521153%28v=vs.92%29.aspx). I hope it helps